# how can you confirm a deliveryslip in odoo using API (Ripcord, and php)

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, ripcord

For my company i would like for the pickers to fill in a html form with the delivery ID, the form will go to the code below. The purpose of the following code is to search the correct delivery slip and confirm it.

When i run the code on my webpage I get the return that everything was successful, but when i Look to the corresponding order in Odoo(10) nothing is changes with the deliveryslip. As I am using the libary and url / db / username / password also for a other script i am sure these are correct.

```
<?php
$deliveryOrderId = $_POST['deliveryOrderId'];

require 'test/ripcord.php';

// Odoo server information
$url = 'xxxx';
$db = 'xxxx';
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxxx';

// Connect to Odoo server and authenticate
$common = ripcord::client($url . '/xmlrpc/2/common');
$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());

if ($uid) {
    // Connect to Odoo's 'stock.picking' model
    $models = ripcord::client($url . '/xmlrpc/2/object');

    // Search for the delivery order based on the provided $deliveryOrderId
    $deliveryOrderIds = $models->execute_kw(
        $db,
        $uid,
        $password,
        'stock.picking',
        'search',
        array(
            array(
                array('id', '=', $deliveryOrderId)
            )
        )
    );

    if ($deliveryOrderIds) {
        // Confirm the delivery order
        $models->execute_kw(
            $db,
            $uid,
            $password,
            'stock.picking',
            'action_confirm',
            array($deliveryOrderIds)
        );

        echo "Delivery order confirmed successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "Delivery order not found.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Authentication failed.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you debugged/stepped through the code to see what is happening with the ``$deliveryOrderIds`` object?  Just because it passes your ``if ($deliveryOrderIds)`` test, doesn't necessarily mean that it contains the value/s that you expect.  It may be that your ``$models->execute_kw(`` ... is ultimately not performing any valid function, but then it just goes on to the next statement and echoes that it was successful.  How sure are you that it is actually doing everything successfully?

Comment: thank you for the responds. But a change me code, to do more then the code above.

Answer (score 0):

The following code gets the variables
$picking_id & $locatie from a html form.
And then search if the ID exists after that it copy's the quantity's to done and then does the do_new_tranfer methode to confirm the picking.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Retrieve values from the form
    $picking_id = intval($_POST["picking_id"]);
    $locatie = $_POST["locatie"];

    require '../ripcord/ripcord.php';

    // Odoo server information
    $url = 'xxxx';
    $db = 'xxxx';
    $username = 'xxx';
    $password = 'xxxxx';

    try {
        // Connect to Odoo server and authenticate
        $common = ripcord::client($url . '/xmlrpc/2/common');
        $uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());

        if (!$uid) {
            throw new Exception("Authentication failed.");
        }

        // Connect to Odoo's 'stock.picking' model
        $models = ripcord::client($url . '/xmlrpc/2/object');

        // Check if the picking exists
        $picking_exists = $models->execute_kw(
            $db,
            $uid,
            $password,
            'stock.picking',
            'search_count',
            array(array(array('id', '=', $picking_id)))
        );

        if (!$picking_exists) {
            throw new Exception("Picking with ID $picking_id not found.");
        }

        // Call the 'copy_qty' method to perform some action on the picking
        $result = $models->execute_kw(
            $db,
            $uid,
            $password,
            'stock.picking',
            'copy_qty',
            array($picking_id)
        );

        if (!$result) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to perform 'copy_qty' action on the picking.");
        } else {
            // Corrected function name and removed extra parenthesis
            $confirm_delivery = $models->execute_kw(
                $db,
                $uid,
                $password,
                'stock.picking',
                'do_new_transfer',
                array($picking_id)
            );

            // Update the x_locatie and x_error fields
            $update_fields = array(
                array($picking_id),
                array('x_locatie' => $locatie, 'x_error' => 'Picking bevestigd door magazijn')
            );
            $models->execute_kw(
                $db,
                $uid,
                $password,
                'stock.picking',
                'write',
                $update_fields
            );
        }

        // Redirect back to index.html with an error message
        header("Location: index.html?response=" . urlencode("Order bevestigd"));
        exit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Redirect back to index.html with an error message
        header("Location: index.html?response=" . urlencode("Error: " . $e->getMessage()));
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```